# To-Infinitive : i saw the boat float/ i reported the boat float?

Tags: grammar

1. I saw the boat float
2. I saw the boat floating
3. I saw the boat navigated
4. I saw the boat being navigated
5. I report the boat to ______???                  to float???

   but: I expect the boat to flow.
6. I reported the boat to be navigated.
7. I reported the boat to have been navigated

All constructions in Active and Passive are clear.
The one I cannot understand is usage of Active voice in №5.

Would usage of «to float» with To-Infinitive be correct or not? Why?
Thank You!

Comment: I don't think ***report*** is idiomatic in many contexts like the examples here anyway, but it's worth noting that Infinitive ***to float*** doesn't work with ***to report*** in #5. Similar verbs where it *does* work include *I **expected, wanted, caused** the boat **to float** [so I was surprised to see it sink]*. Other verbs require different syntax: *I **hoped, predicted, assumed** it **would float***, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Since we expect a boat to be floating, it seems an unlikely thing for anyone to say. (5) would be more idiomatically expressed as *I report that the boat is [still] floating* (if there was some doubt of its seaworthiness!). The construction *report [something] to be...* is used with adjectives rather than verbs - *He reported the boat to be still afloat.*

Answer (score 1):

Different words subcategorise for different kinds of argument.

*See* can take a noun phrase, a *that* clause, a bare infinitive clause, an *-ing* clause, but not normally a *to-* infinitive clause.

*Expect* can take a noun phrase, a *that* clause, a *to-* infinitive clause, but not a bare infinitive or *-ing* clause.

*Report* can take a noun phrase, or a *that* clause.

There is no rule or logic to this: its just a property of the particular words that has to be learnt.

Comment: Colin Fine, thank you! I appreciate your explanation, it makes sense now. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

"Report" usually does not take an infinitive argument. However, it can in some situations, including with "to be":

> The food critic reported the meal to be excellent.
> The messenger reported the battle to be lost.

and when it is in the passive voice:

> The groundhog was reported to emerge on warm days.
> The candidate was reported to have lost the election.

You could thus write:

> The journalist reported the boat to be floating.
> The boat was reported to float!

As Colin Fine mentions, the rules vary for different categories of verbs. If you search Stack Exchange, you'll find more in-depth discussions of this issue, e.g.: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/heard-me-infinitive-vs-heard-me-present-participle